# Deal with an irregular nested list from a JSON in R

Tags: r, json, nested-lists

I am currently struggling quite seriously to extract (important) data from a tricky Json file in R.
Well, technically it's a file extracted from a MongoDB database but it doesn't change the problem at all when it comes to the structure issue.

First of all, here is the nasty json with its structure (JSON editor online). It's a short version (4 objects) but enough to see problems with lists in columns:
[Structure of the json file](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=fc3c963910f1343d4e6bf35cdeb09bb2)
I scanned most of the StackOverflow topics explaining how to deal with nested lists from Jsons but couldn't manage to solve the problem yet. For simplification, I will put the code without the Mongo query but use the absolute path of my json file. It has a structure similar to the json I linked above.

The code I used it extremely simple, I took it from a StackO topic about a similar issue:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(jsonlite)
#Simple import with jsonlite
data <- fromJSON("C:/mypersonnalpath/apps.json", flatten = TRUE) # flatten = TRUE, supposed to flattens list columns
data <- data[, c("app.id", "app.hosts","app.fluxList","app.interventions","app.microservices")] # just for simplification, I select annoying columns and the app.id
```

This little code gives me something like this:
[Aspect of the data with nested lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyMLm.png)

It's like having tables in cells, sometimes with one obs, sometimes with three, sometimes 2 columns, sometimes 3... It's tricky to deal with complex json structure at my level, far from being a beast with R...

I did try the unnest() function from the tidyverse package, but it doesn't work and put this error message (example with the column app.hosts to make it as simple as possible):

```
> unnest(data, app.hosts)
Error: Each column must either be a list of vectors or a list of data frames 
[app.hosts]
```

Make a loop to convert all these "NULL" or "list()" into a lists of vectors didn't help of course, because the problem is deeper, or my loop is bad (definitely possible too), or both (highest probability). But something's wrong somewhere and I can't put my finger on what it is.

If I could flatten this stupid column "app.host" that would be already a good step ahead...
I don't even know if it's possible to flatten this kind column. I'm kinda confused now :/

Thank you in advance for everything. I will add more infos if it's necessary. I hope one of you guys will have a good idea about this; The json file should work in R.

Joe

Edit:
Dealing with these list is quite tricky and I don't really know what would be the best option to gather all the infos clearly for an incoming analysis (like network graphs blablabla...). But I already know it will increase the size of the dataset by repeating lines with only one change

Anyway, I my mind, this would give something like this:

For example, for the first row in the image I linked, (app.id = 45)

`app.id + app.hosts.host.hostname1 + app.hosts.host.env1 + ...
 45    |         "ATOME"          |        ""`

(next columns)

`app.hosts.host.notes1 + app.hosts.host.ip1 +
"YYY Actionnaraire"   |       Na            |`

And repeat these columns for the second dimension in the vector, third if necessary, fourth...
The app.hosts list in the json is like this, with 3 app.hosts.host that I will have to transform into columns. Same for the three other columns that contain lists and that are visible in the picture I posted:

```js
    "hosts": [
        {
          "host": {
            "hostname": "ATOME",
            "env": "",
            "notes": "YYY Actionnaraire"
          }
        },
        {
          "host": {
            "hostname": "SQL-BUR",
            "env": "Prod",
            "notes": "CHL;Server SQL"
          }
        },
        {
          "host": {
            "hostname": "",
            "ip": ""
          }
        }
      ]
```

It's a little bit annoying :[
Or, If someone knows how to extract infos for a analysis with graphs and other goodies in R, I won't have to flatten this stuff...

Comment: Hi Joe - can you please provide us with a snippet of your desired output?  Providing the JSON itself is great, but knowing what you want to do with it will allow us to help you parse the file.

Comment: It might be easier to rewrite the mongo query to `$unwind` the nested arrays during the query process, rather than trying to do it in R

Comment: Thank you guys. Erik, I edited my first post, if you gather infos that might help you... I'm not sure, I did my best for the moment to explain a problem I can't solve lol. SymbolixAU, I have a problem with the json in Mongo because when I unwind these for nested lists, it repeats the "_id" : ObjectId("....") and refuse to $out the new collection.